# Detect timeout in WPF UI thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is it possible in WPF to detect UI thread freezing for a given time and support such situations? (Eg. by throwing a proper exception if the given operation in UI thread takes more time than given threshold).

I cannot move the potentially long-running operation from the UI thread, because of dependencies on 3rd party library.

Comment: Before starting the UI thread process, start a nanny thread that wakes up every second or so and checks a completion flag that the UI thread sets. Make it a real synchronization object if you must. If your maximum allowed time passes and the UI thread is still zonked out, invoke into the UI thread and throw an exception.

Comment: What that third party library do? Maybe you can run it in separate UI thread. Its possible to detect freeze, but it might be not possible to interrupt it without tearing down whole process (you cannot throw exception on UI thread because its already busy).